# Restricting user input

Tags: c++, input, enums, switch-statement

I am making a simple program, where user needs to enter a few possible characters. I want possible inputs to be only i, c, l, v, h, k, f, s, x. I do realize I can do something like:

```
char a;
bool s(false);    
cin>>a;
do
{
switch(a)
case 'i': ...
case 'c': ...
...
default: cout<<"Invalid input! Try again: "; cin>>a; s=true;
} while(s);
```

However, I am pretty sure there is a more gracious solution. I am guessing enumerations would be involved. Would anyone be so kind as to tell it to me, since I could not find absolutely anything on the subject.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that what you don't like is that incorrect character is also echoed on the screen and that's why you are printing "Invalid input"? If user input won't be echoed and you'll need to echo it yourself but only if an accepted character  is entered, will it solve your problem?

Comment: If the user is only inputting a single character then a switch statement really is the best solution to this. I suppose you could have long 'if' statements, e.g. if (a == 'i' || a == 'c' || etc...) but that just seems far messier IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution could be:

```
const string allowed{"iclvhkfsx"};
while (  cin.get(a) && allowed.find(a)== string::npos)
   cout << "Incorect input, try again ! ";
```

The code loops until a valid char is entered (or eof is reached).

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/JXJGNN)

Such a solution could be generalized to other data types than chars by using `basic_string<T>` ([demo for integers](http://ideone.com/oM9kmv)).  Of course, `switch` is perfectly valid, but I think its benefit is higher whenever different input would most often require different processing.